# Where is the recycle bin location in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003

A friend has no net access at the moment and he has asked me if I can tell him the path to the recycle bin on Windows Server 2003? Ive put stuff like 'windows server 2003 recycle bin directory location' into google but Im not getting any answers. So does anyone here know?

Answer (score 6):

[Raymond Chen](http://microsoftjobsblog.com/blog/raymond-chen/), from Microsoft, has written the following blog post: [Why does the Recycle Bin have different file system names on FAT and NTFS?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060131-00/?p=32453)

From that blog post, let me quote the section that seems to be more relevant to this effect:

> All recycled files on FAT drives are dumped into a single C:\RECYCLED
> directory, whereas recycled files on NTFS drives are separated based
> on the user's SID into directories named C:\RECYCLER\S-....

I have just checked a Windows Server 2003 computer with disks formatted in NTFS and indeed there is a "RECYCLER" hidden directory / folder in C:\ and, under that "RECYCLER" directory, there are several (also) hidden sub-directories with names started by "S-"

I hope this helps.